# What does this notation mean, concerning a vector?

Tags: statistics, notation, vectors, noise

I am currently reading a paper, in which the following system is defined:
$$
\dot x(t) = f(x) + \varepsilon\sigma(x)\xi(t) \tag{1}
$$
Where $x(t)$ is an $n$-vector, $f(x)$ is some $n$-vector transformation function, $\xi(t)$ us an $m$-dimensional standard white Gaussian noise with parameters $\langle \xi(t)\rangle = 0,~\langle\xi(t)\xi^\mathsf{T}(\tau)\rangle = \delta(t-\tau)I$, $\varepsilon$ is the scalar parameter of the noise intensity, and $\sigma(x)$ is an $n\times m$-matrix-valued function of the random disturbances.

And here, I do not understand, what does the notation $\langle\xi(t)\rangle$ mean, once $\xi(t)$ is a vector.

I mean, I have already seen such notation, but its meaning was different, as for example, for some vectors $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$, $\langle \boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{v}\rangle$ would be a dot-product of theirs, and $\langle\boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{v}\rangle = 0$ only once $\boldsymbol{u} \perp \boldsymbol{v}$. Or alternatively, as far as I know, in group theory, $\langle g \rangle$ where $g\in G$, indicates the cyclic subgroup of $G$, generated by its element of $g$.

In $(1)$ I completely fail to understand, what the notation means. I have rather a guess, that it may indicate "kind-of" expected value of a vector, since we assume the Gaussian white noise, but I have never seen such operations with vectors before, so that I cannot expand my thought on this any further..

I would be glad, if anyone could help me out with identifying, what such a notation may mean. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some kind of integral I guess.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea can you, please, expand a bit on your guess?

Comment: It is some kind of functional map, taking in function and putting out a value, so I think it's an integral. But I can't figure out which measure it uses without further information. The two example you give show that the noise is unbiased and pairwise independent about time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, given the context, that this notation is for the expected value.  So $\langle\xi(t)\rangle=0$ would mean that $\xi(t)$ is zero mean, all of the entries of the vector are zero mean.

As was suggested as an additional clarification by [O.spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/719128/o-spectrum):

$$\langle \xi(t)\rangle = \mathbb E\xi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{E}\xi_1(t)\\\vdots\\\mathbb{E}\xi_m(t)\end{pmatrix} = \boldsymbol{0}_{[m\times 1]}$$

Comment: So, that is something like: $\langle \xi(t)\rangle = \mathbb E\xi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{E}\xi_1(t)\\\vdots\\\mathbb{E}\xi_m(t)\end{pmatrix} = \boldsymbol{0}_{[m\times 1]}$, am I right?

Comment: @O.spectrum, yes, I believe so.  I will add your interpretation to my answer.

Comment: Oh, alright. I actually support your interpretation, as for me it also seemed reasonable that, as far as we withdraw noise-instances according to Gaussian distribution, then the mean-value of each of such point-observed noise instances is also zero, just I was not that sure.

Thank you a lot for your answer, I am going to accept it though :)